# Rails Redis session store is not working on heroku? User logs out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, heroku

Issue:

I have rails 5.2 application running on  heroku I am using sidkiq & spree. Right now when I login into any account I am automatically logged out after 5-6 mins

```
  config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
  config.session_store :cache_store, key: '_spree_test_session'
```

This is configration I have in staging env.

I read about [heroku Session Affinity](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/session-affinity) but I think that will solve our problem when we use mem cache, I am already using redis for storing session so it is supposed to work fine

Any thoughts and suggestions are welcome?

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem.  Trying to understand how to persist sessions across restarts of the app server.